# Stimulsoft Report require to Refresh after Save button

Tags: report, stimulsoft

When I click on Save for PDF report then again I am not able to click on Save. I require to refresh the page.

Is this is default behavior?

[Save Button Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2sVi.png)

Please help me.

Comment: What Viewer do you use? What version?

Comment: Currently, I am using 2013 Version.